# Not understanding the Boolean Logic to my method

Tags: ruby

I write the method capitalized(word) to be funneled into the .each function. 
i use bang! to make the function work correctly but i don't understand why its working correctly. 
The part that is really throwing me off is the !capitalized word line if statement. I don't understand the logic and how the method returns the answers that it does. 
!false returns false in the method... why? And !true it returns true. 
Whats the best way to understand this concept.

I have tried taking out the bang and putting it back in to see its effect. 
And it just confuses me. Thank you for your help.

```
# A name is valid is if satisfies all of the following:
# - contains at least a first name and last name, separated by spaces
# - each part of the name should be capitalized
#
# Hint: use str.upcase or str.downcase
# "a".upcase # => "A"

def is_valid_name(str)
  name = str.split(' ')

  if name.length < 2
    return false
  end

  name.each do |word|
    if !capitalized(word)
      return false
    end
  end
  return true
end

def capitalized(word)
  if word[0] == word[0].upcase && word[1..-1]== word[1..-1].downcase
    return true
  else
    return false
  end
end



puts is_valid_name("Kush Patel")       # => true
puts is_valid_name("Daniel")           # => false
puts is_valid_name("Robert Downey Jr") # => true
puts is_valid_name("ROBERT DOWNEY JR") # => false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The purpose of the part of the code you struggling with, is to check whether all of the elements of the name are capitalised. There are two ways you can approach that problem:

**Find any element that is not capitalised.**

If such element exists, that means name is not valid, so method `is_valid_name` should return `false`. This is the approach used in you code:

```
def is_valid_name(str)
  #...
  name.each do |word| #1
    if !capitalized(word) #2
      return false #3 
    end
  end
  return true #4
end
```

1. Iterate over every part of the name
2. Check if word is capitalized. We want to break only when we find invalid (not capitalized) word. That occurs when `capitalized(word)` returns `false`: so condition `if !capitalized(word)` is actually `if !false`, which is equal to `if true`.
3. We entered, that means our word is not valid, so we return false from `is_valid_name` method.

**Check if all elements are capitalized**

This is more straightforward solution. We just want to check, if method `capitalized(word)` returns true for all of the elements of the name.

To achieve that, we can use method [all?](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/all%3F), which returns true if condition in the block returns true for every element; otherwise false. So we can replace all the code above with single line:

```
name.all?{|word| capitalized(word) }
```

Final implementation of the validation method can look like that:

```
def is_valid_name(str)
  name = str.split(' ')
  name.length < 2 && name.all?{|word| capitalized(word)}
end
```

Hope it helps you!

Answer (score 0):

> `!false` returns `false` in the method... why?

I'm assuming you mean this one:

```
if !capitalized(word)
  return false
end
```

"If `capitalize` returns false, why do we return false", this question? Because if a word is not capitalized, the name is invalid. That's the given business logic.